# Troubleshooting network problems in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr

Tags: networking, dns, ubuntu-14.04

So I seem to have two problems.  My first problem is that I can only intermittently `ping` my router from my Ubuntu Desktop (by IP address).  Second, my Ubuntu Desktop intermittently fails to properly perform DNS ("DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET"/"Can't find server"). Please note the term intermittently.  I assume the two are connected, but I can't quite be certain.

Everything about the network works - it's definitely the Desktop.  I'm actually writing this post from a VM I'm running on the Destkop - I've never had any network problems with this VM's network - full network and Internet access, on demand, with full performance.

I would like to be able to manually configure the network (`/etc/resolv.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces`), but the `NetworkManager` and `dnsmasq` and `resolconf` keep overwriting settings and generally obscuring what's actually happening with the network.  I'll settle for any answers, though - getting away from the NetworkManager and other tools just seems like the simplest start to understanding the problem.

I've done a lot of looking over the last couple weeks, and seen several forums, but nothing seems to work for me.  Removing `dnsmasq` and `resolvconf` hasn't worked (I haven't tried removing `network-manager`, though).  Putting DNS server entries in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` hasn't helped.  Manual entries in `resolv.conf` and `interfaces` gets overwritten (no surprise).

For some background, my desktop is a hard-wired network connection (cat5) running directly to my router, with a static IP and internall-configured DNS settings pointing to several public DNS servers, e.g. Google (i.e., DNS servers had been configured through NetworkManager - not received via DHCP).  Nothing is "new" about this configuration - it was running steady for months until this popped up about 6 weeks ago.  It doesn't seem to vary by time of day, or Desktop demand, or total demand on the router.  It just "happens" sometimes for 30 seconds, sometimes for 2 hours.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before... bad cable.  So it could be that simple, have you tried using a brand new CAT-6 or CAT-5e cable?

Could be a bad physical port on either end that is just not seating properly anymore.

This could also be something esoteric like bad switch firmware that is causing a random link drop and subsequent spanning-tree CAM table blocking/learning (30 second delay of traffic).

Beyond that, you can purge resolvconf along with ubuntu-minimal, unfortunately you cannot delete dnsmasq-base as a few core packages, including network-manager, have a Depends set for it, but you can do this to stop it from actually starting and messing with system stuff:

```
$ sudo mv /usr/sbin/dnsmasq /usr/sbin/dnsmasq.off
$ sudo ln /bin/true /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
$ sudo chattr +i /usr/sbin/dnsmasq
```

This will fake out the system into thinking it does something (just exits "true") though it didn't, and still satisfies the Depends in apt for network-manager.  And you get to keep your sanity.  I've done this with good results, no more messing with /etc/resolv.conf (only my VPN messes with it now).

Just keep in mind if dnsmasq package is upgraded, you may have to re-do this.  I suggest you put a Hold on it.